# Lower bound on the sum of numbers of a set with no 3-term arithmetic progression

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that the set $S_A$ contains all possible sums of two elements in set $A$. Let $A$ be any set of $n$ elements where $A$ contains no $3$-arithmetic progressions. Can we prove anything about what is the minimum cardinality of $S_A$ such that $A$ is a set of $n$ elements which do not form any $3$-arithmetic progressions.

(I.e. in other words, what I'm interested in is the cardinality of $S_A$. My concern is then does a set of $n$ elements that do not form $3$-arithmetic progressions exist to minimize $|S_A|$ and what is this minimum in terms of $n$.)

Comment: For clarity: It is the "generating set" $A$ which is to have no 3 term progressions, and then from $A$ you form the other set $S_A$ consisting of sums of two elements from $A$ and want to minimize the size of $S_A$ given the size of $A$..right? Also in forming the sums to make $S_A$ can one include $a+a$ or are the sums to be of distinct elements of $A$?

Comment: 1) Yes, the generating set $A$ must have no 3-term progressions. 2) $S_A$ is the generated set. 3) I want to minimize the size of $S_A$ in terms of $n$, the number of elements in $A$. 4) The sums must be of distinct elements of $A$. For example, $a + a$ would not be in $S_A$.

Comment: q2liu Thanks for the comment, which clarifies the question. An interesting one, by the way!